# Change LibSassBuilder output directory

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side, libsass

I'm using [LibSassBuilder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibSassBuilder) in a Blazor project. I have read the docs and it's unclear to me if the package's config allows you to specify an output directory. I'd prefer to keep my `.scss` files outside of `wwwroot` and just place the compiled `.css` files there-- but I don't see if there's a way to do this. If not, is there a way to specify a file move to `wwwroot` in the Visual Studio build pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also developing a Blazor project using LibSassBuilder. This is how I got it to work in my **.csproj** file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <LibSassOutputStyle>compressed</LibSassOutputStyle>
    <LibSassOutputStyle Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">expanded</LibSassOutputStyle>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <CSSFiles Include="**/*.css" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="MoveCSS" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Move SourceFiles="@(CSSFiles)" DestinationFolder="wwwroot/css" />
</Target>
```